# how convert xml to object on java spring-boot

Tags: java, xml, object, spring-boot

hello I'm trying to convert xml with number of objects and I get an
error message : The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="test.example.com">
  <Item>
    <ItemKey>1111</ItemKey>
    <Start>2/10/2017</Start>
    <customNumber>12</customNumber>
    <End>2/10/2018</End>
    <Account>2221111</Account>
    <Name>John</Name>
    <Note>GOOD</Note>
    <CodeNo>4444-1</CodeNo>
    <Source>www.cnn.com</Source>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <ItemKey>2222</ItemKey>
    <Start>2/10/2017</Start>
    <customNumber>75</customNumber>
    <End>2/10/2018</End>
    <Account>3333111</Account>
    <Name>Smith</Name>
    <Note>NOT GOOD</Note>
    <CodeNo>4444-2</CodeNo>
    <Source>www.fox.com</Source>
  </Item>
</string>
```

Model Class:

```
package example.models;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "Item")
public class Model {

private String CodeNo;

private String ItemKey;

private String Start;

private String End;

private String Account;

private String Name;

private String Note;

...(gets and sets)
```

main Code:

```
StringReader reader = new StringReader(response);
String response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);
...

 JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Model.class);
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            Model recordes = (Model) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
```

unmarshal exception:
 The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.

xml with only one item the code work.

what I missing and need to do to get list of element (items) object without error ?

Answer (score 4):

In the XML file your root element is `<string xmlns="test.example.com">` tag so either correct the XML or correct the Model class to get it work.

To understand more about the error check this [How to fix error: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46355454/how-to-fix-error-the-markup-in-the-document-following-the-root-element-must-be)

**edit**

You can use this tool to generate the POJO : http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com

here are the POJO classes for above XML:

```
public class MyXML
{
    private String string; // Change the class as String is Wrapper class

    public String getString ()
    {
        return string;
    }

    public void setString (String string)
    {
        this.string = string;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [string = "+string+"]";
    }
}
```

String class:

```
public class String // Change this className as String is Wrapper class in java
{
    private Item[] Item;

    private String xmlns;

    public Item[] getItem ()
    {
        return Item;
    }

    public void setItem (Item[] Item)
    {
        this.Item = Item;
    }

    public String getXmlns ()
    {
        return xmlns;
    }

    public void setXmlns (String xmlns)
    {
        this.xmlns = xmlns;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [Item = "+Item+", xmlns = "+xmlns+"]";
    }
}
```

Items class

```
public class Item
{
    private String Name;

    private String Source;

    private String End;

    private String CodeNo;

    private String Start;

    private String Account;

    private String ItemKey;

    private String Note;

    private String customNumber;

    public String getName ()
    {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName (String Name)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
    }

    public String getSource ()
    {
        return Source;
    }

    public void setSource (String Source)
    {
        this.Source = Source;
    }

    public String getEnd ()
    {
        return End;
    }

    public void setEnd (String End)
    {
        this.End = End;
    }

    public String getCodeNo ()
    {
        return CodeNo;
    }

    public void setCodeNo (String CodeNo)
    {
        this.CodeNo = CodeNo;
    }

    public String getStart ()
    {
        return Start;
    }

    public void setStart (String Start)
    {
        this.Start = Start;
    }

    public String getAccount ()
    {
        return Account;
    }

    public void setAccount (String Account)
    {
        this.Account = Account;
    }

    public String getItemKey ()
    {
        return ItemKey;
    }

    public void setItemKey (String ItemKey)
    {
        this.ItemKey = ItemKey;
    }

    public String getNote ()
    {
        return Note;
    }

    public void setNote (String Note)
    {
        this.Note = Note;
    }

    public String getCustomNumber ()
    {
        return customNumber;
    }

    public void setCustomNumber (String customNumber)
    {
        this.customNumber = customNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [Name = "+Name+", Source = "+Source+", End = "+End+", CodeNo = "+CodeNo+", Start = "+Start+", Account = "+Account+", ItemKey = "+ItemKey+", Note = "+Note+", customNumber = "+customNumber+"]";
    }
}
```

Comment: how I need to add xmlns to spring boot model ?

Comment: @MrK, Edited my answer is that you were looking or something else?

Comment: ok and how I need combine this with :
 JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Model.class);
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            Model recordes = (Model) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);

Answer (score 3):

**Step by step process for creating XML to object in Springboot**

1. First, you need to create maven project give Group id and Artifact id.

2.Create your java class in src/main/java and your package name and your java class name for Example-XmlToJavaObject.java

3.Convert your XML code into POJO class using below link

http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/Convert

It will create POJO class according to your XML data.
Create a package for POJO and put All POJO classes into this folder.

4. Put your XML file in this project near pom.xml.
5. Create main method into XmlToJavaObject.java class.

I am Writing below code but you can change it according to your requirements.

Our Example XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <Student>
        <id>1111</id>
        <name>Ravi</name>
        <age>12</age>
        <dob>2/10/2008</dob>
    </Student>
```

Our Model class

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

    @XmlRootElement
        public class Student
        {
            private String dob;

            private String name;

            private String id;

            private String age;

            public String getDob ()
            {
                return dob;
            }

            public void setDob (String dob)
            {
                this.dob = dob;
            }

            public String getName ()
            {
                return name;
            }

            public void setName (String name)
            {
                this.name = name;
            }

            public String getId ()
            {
                return id;
            }

            public void setId (String id)
            {
                this.id = id;
            }

            public String getAge ()
            {
                return age;
            }

            public void setAge (String age)
            {
                this.age = age;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString()
            {
                return "ClassPojo [dob = "+dob+", name = "+name+", id = "+id+", age = "+age+"]";
            }
        }
```

Our Main Class Example

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;  
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;  
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

import com.test.pojo.Student;


public class XmlToJavaObject {


    public static void main(String ar[])
    {
         try {  

                File file = new File("Student.xml");  
                JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Student.class);  

                Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();  
                Student student= (Student) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);  


                System.out.println(student.getName());


              } catch (JAXBException e) {  
                e.printStackTrace();  
              }
    }
}
```

Output

```
Ravi
```

Comment: Thank you, with **@XmlRootElement** it could convert all the nested objects itself

Answer (score 0):

With this library: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html

[convert xml to java object using jaxb (unmarshal)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11221136/convert-xml-to-java-object-using-jaxb-unmarshal)

Answer (score -1):

```
int PRETTY_PRINT_INDENT_FACTOR = 4;
String TEST_XML_STRING =
        "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?><test attrib=\"moretest\">Turn this to 
JSON</test>";

try {
     JSONObject xmlJSONObj = XML.toJSONObject(TEST_XML_STRING);
     String jsonPrettyPrintString = 
xmlJSONObj.toString(PRETTY_PRINT_INDENT_FACTOR);
     System.out.println(jsonPrettyPrintString);
} catch (JSONException je) {
     System.out.println(je.toString());
}
```

hope this will help you, use [org.json](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20140107) jar file

Comment: i need object not json, any suggestion?

Comment: Object obj=(Object)xmlJSONObj;