# Unmarshal Xml components to Java Object using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling, externalinterface

I've done marshalling java object to XML elements.
Now I face a difficulty to unmarshal XML file to java object using JAXB.
Is it similar as marshalling java object to XML?
Below is the XML file that I got from the external API.

```
<ShoppingMall>
  <ProductList>
    <product_info>
      <group_nm>electronic device</group_nm>
      <group_code>e001</group_code>
      <product_nm>computer</product_nm>
      <price>30000</price>
    </product_info>
    <product_info>
      <group_nm>living</group_nm>
      <group_code>lv002</group_code>
      <product_nm>bed</product_nm>
      <price>140000</price>
    </product_info>
    <product_info>
      <group_nm>Food</group_nm>
      <group_code>f001</group_code>
      <product_nm>pasta</product_nm>
      <price>10</price>
    </product_info>    
  </ProductList>
</ShoppingMall>
```

To exchange XML element to java object, what should I do with JAXB?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert xml to java object using jaxb (unmarshal)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11221136/convert-xml-to-java-object-using-jaxb-unmarshal)

Answer (score 0):

firstly create three java classes for,

- ShoppingMall (ProductList is a xml element in this class)
- ProductList (product_info is a xml element in this class)
- product_info (group_nm, group_code, product_nm and price are xml elements in this class)

then try with this,

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ShoppingMall.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
ShoppingMall shoppingMall = (ShoppingMall) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal( new File("your_xml_file.xml") );
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to unmarshal to ShoppingMall class. So, you might write something like this.

```html
ShoppingMall shoppingMall = getShoppignMallByUnmarshal(your_xml);
  
  public static getShoppignMallByUnmarshal(
      String xml) throws JAXBException
  {
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(package.path.of.ShoppingClass.ObjectFactory.class);
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    return ((JAXBElement<ShoppingMall>) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(xml)))
        .getValue();
  }
```